# How to slow down SVG stroke dashoffset and stroke dashoffset line animation

Tags: css, svg

Hi how do slow I down SVG stroke dashoffset and stroke dashoffset line animation?

I would like to have the lines draw at a slower pace. Codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/MrThunder/pen/mJmRqa)

```
.st0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#231F20;
    stroke-width:3;
}
.st2{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#231F20;
    stroke-miterlimit:10;
    stroke-width:3;
}
.st0,.st2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 958;
    stroke-dashoffset: 958;
    animation: dash 2s 5s linear forwards;
   webkit-animation:  dash 2s 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes filling {
    0% {
        fill: #231F20;
    }
    100% {
        fill: #D6D3BB;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the animation duration doesn't work?

Comment: No it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Your CodePen is broken.  There are several things wrong with it.  We shouldn't have to debug your sample before getting to the actual problem you asked about.

Comment: Excuse me? What is wrong with it? This is supposed to be a place of learning and answers. I gave out a working example of my problem, I did not know it needed to be debugged. If I did know the all the mistakes then I would not require any assistance would I? I appreciate your answer below but I do not appreciate this snide comment, you probably are having a bad day or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the duration works fine for me (once I fixed the other things that were wrong with your sample.

```
animation: dash 2s 5s linear forwards;
```

There are two time values in this animation rule.  The first one (`2s`) is the animation duration. The second (`5s`) is the delay before the animation starts running.  To make the animation run slower, make the first number bigger.

```
animation: dash 8s 5s linear forwards;
```

This will work for Firefox, but be aware that Chrome still uses prefixed values for `animation` because the CSS animation specification is not completely finalised yet.  So for Chrome you need to include the following:

```
-webkit-animation: dash 8s 5s linear forwards;
```

as well as the `@-webkit-keyframe` block.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbvdZy)